# Save Image from Canvas not working

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, surfaceview

I want to save the canvas from a SurfaceView to a bitmap to store it on the smartphone. I've searched for some tutorials and tried it like this:

```
public void saveImage(){
    Canvas canv = this.holder.lockCanvas();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canv.getWidth(), canv.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    this.holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canv);

    this.view.draw(canvas);

    try{
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, new FileOutputStream(new File("/SD-Karte/Pictures/test.png")));
    } catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("Error --->", e.toString());
    }
}
```

When I click the button to save the image, my app just stops working and I'm getting no error. Any hints from you guys what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If it just stops it is getting an error, if it freezes it is because your main thread is clogged. Have you checked your logcat to see what is going on?

Comment: i get `code 31967-31967/com.example.standardbenutzer.adelpath E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.standardbenutzer.adelpath, PID: 31967
    java.lang.NullPointerException` at "this.view.draw(canvas);"

Comment: view is null. You ever set view to anything?

Comment: `code     DrawingView view = (DrawingView)findViewById(R.id.surface);
this.holder = view.getHolder();
`

it can't be null otherwise the whole drawing wouldn't work!

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, that code either means this or view is null. I really don't think this can even be null, so it has to be view. Put a breakpoint at that line (or do a log, Log.d(TAG, "View == " view)) and make sure your view isn't null.